# How to add tags to identify custom post types in archives?

Tags: tags

The most important thing I would like to add that is missing from my site is colored post type tags for each of my 7 custom post types within the category archives, search archives, and tag archives (which all use the same template file). I was able to manually add colored post type tags to each of the 7 single.php files by adding the following code (this one is for single-articles.php):

```
<div class="post-type-articles-container pull-left"><a href="http://collectivelyconscious.net/articles">Articles</a></div>;
```

I think that what I need for the archive template is for the 7 codes for each post type to be there within the loop, but it needs to be conditional or something depending on which post type is being called. I just don't know what the PHP code is that I need to use to do this. Here is what I have added to the archive template in order to get the custom taxonomies for each custom post type to work:

```
<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'articles-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div>

<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'questions-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div>

<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'videos-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div>

<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'documentaries-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div> 

<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'ted-talks-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div>

<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'memes-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div>

<div class="post-category-container pull-left"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'music-archives', ' ', '<br />' ); ?></div>
```

And here is the code for the tags that appears just after it:

```
<div class="pull-left"><?php the_tags('<div class="post-tags">', ' ', '</div>'); ?></div>
```

So I'm assuming I would need to add similar PHP code as what is used for the taxonomy terms, but I just don't know what it is... Does anyone know?

Comment: You mean add post tags to CPTs and custom taxonomy types?

Comment: I think adding an example of the final output you want would help us answer.

Comment: By default if you call post_class() in the wrapper for each item in an archive, it will insert the custom post type name of that item as a class. Then you could target anything within that wrapper with custom styles, including the tags. 

If each custom post type has different associated taxonomies, that's sort of a different question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: So if you go to the following address you will see the colored tag (red) that links to the archives for the custom post type 'articles': http://collectivelyconscious.net/articles/the-marvelous-properties-of-gamma-brain-waves/

Comment: But then if you go to the archives for 'articles' you only see the custom taxonomy tags for that CPT and the normal tags after it. I would like the archive template (which is used for all archives, including search and tag archives) to have the correct colored CPT tag for each post. Here is a link to the 'articles' archives without the colored CPT tags: http://collectivelyconscious.net/articles/

Comment: And here is the link to the tag archive for the word "neuroscience", which contains posts that have been added to the 'articles', 'videos', and 'ted-talks' archives, only you can't tell the difference between any of them. This is the problem: http://collectivelyconscious.net/tag/neuroscience/

Answer (score 0):

I got it :)

```
<?php
if ( 'articles' == get_post_type() ) {
?>
<div class="post-type-articles-container pull-left post-tag-margin"><a href="http://collectivelyconscious.net/articles">Articles</a></div>
<?php
}
?>

<?php
if ( 'questions' == get_post_type() ) {
?>
<div class="post-type-questions-container pull-left post-tag-margin"><a href="http://collectivelyconscious.net/questions">Questions</a></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

...etc.